# How to visually emphasize one card among many

Tags: website-design, layout, feedback, wireframe, portfolio

I'm working on a portfolio and I want to present myself as "T-shaped designer", so I sorted my works into 3 different categories. These categories will be shown as clickable cards/gallery folders (whatever you may call it).

The problem is one of those categories should draw more attention than the rest to represent the "Stem of the T" in my skillset. I tried a few approaches like having one card with a highly contrasting background, or a stroke around the particular card (which looked more like a hover action). This is the wireframe.

[image]

Any ideas on how I can draw more attention to the first card? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use card size to show dominance in one area of your skillset. The other two can be subordinated, like this:

[image: Three skill cards. The UX-UI Design card is twice as large as the other two.]